# Throwing exception on missing property in Jackson upon deserialization

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I am using jackson 2.12 and lombok 1.18.22.

I have a class

```
@Data
@With
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
Class A {
    int i;
    int j;
}
```

`String value = "{\"i\"=1}"`

I want `new ObjectMapper().readValue(i, A.class)`  to throw an error for missing the field `j` instead it sets the field to `0`.

Comment: This code should be throwing an exception. Have you defined any other constructor for your class?

Comment: Yes, I do have a NoArgsConstuctor as well

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you annotate your all args constructor with the [`JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation and the same time annotate your required *j* field with the [`JsonProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) annotation with `required` set to *true*:

```
@Data
@With
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class A {

    int i;
    int j;

    @JsonCreator
    public A(@JsonProperty(value = "i") int i, 
             @JsonProperty(value = "j", required = true) int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

}
```